# Создание формы обратной связи на битрикс

Tags: битрикс

В стандартном компоненте "Форма обратной связи" есть поля "Имя", "Email", "Сообщения". Как добавить ещё поля, без всяких решений из marketplace, например "День рождения" "Телефон"

Comment: Посмотрите откуда компонент берет данные. Если из инфоблока, то добавьте свойства в инфоблок. Если из "Сервисы"-"Веб-формы", то добавляйте там поля.

Comment: ни то, ни другое. Стандартная "форма обратной связи" из вкладки "Служебные"

Comment: Да уже увидел не смог посмотреть сразу посольку сайт с докой по битриксу лежал. Нашел решение, которое должно вам подойти. Опубликовал в ответе.

Answer (score 1):

Поскольку форма обратной связи в битрикс является стандартным компонентом движка она обновляется вместе с движком, и чтобы обновления не касались изменений внесенных в форму руками нужно сделать свое пространство имен. Для этого копируются основные папки модуля и создаются новые.

Создаем папки:

```
/bitrix/components/newform/
/bitrix/templates/ваш_шаблон/components/newform/
```

Копируем:

```
/bitrix/components/bitrix/main.feedback/ в /bitrix/components/newform/main.feedback/
/components/main.feedback/ в /bitrix/templates/ваш_шаблон/components/newform/main.feedback/
```

И далее модифицируем компонент. Подобный вопрос подробно рассматривается [в этой статье](http://arozhk.ru/blog/html/izmenenie-formy-obratnoj-svyazi-v-bitriks)

Answer (score 0):

Просто модифицируйте шаблон компонента, а дальнейшую обработку можно вести перед отправкой почтового события

`AddEventHandler('main', 'OnBeforeEventSend', "my_OnBeforeEventSend");
       function my_OnBeforeEventSend($arFields, $arTemplate)
       {
            if($arFields["EVENT_NAME"]==FEEDBACK_FORM){//Не помню как точно назвается параметр собержащий тип почтового событие

```
         //обрабатываем поля сообщения
         }



   }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Хоть Вы и отказываетесь от marketplace но я очень рекомендую посмотреть в сторону этого бесплатного модуля который идеально кастомизируется https://marketplace.1c-bitrix.ru/solutions/altasib.feedback/